Sony WH1000XM4 headphones - Custom control for Android App
I'm currently building an Android gym app, and I would like to add some possibility to control it via my headphones. But I don't really know where to go from there, because it seems like there is no direct possibility. I was thinking about two ways of doing it:

There is a touchpad that allows to pause / play the song, go to next / previous song. Maybe I could catch those events in my app, but I think that I need to have something running (either music or video) for the controls to work; moreover I don't know if I could cancel the pause/play events after cathing them, nor if it fires on my app before on Spotify / whatever music player.

Doing something directly with the headphones: there is a CUSTOM button on the headphones, and the app allows to customize it (but very limited, like either noise control / Google Assistant). I've not found anything done related to this, and it looks like some reverse engineering stuff; is it possible to go into this direction and to either catch the Google Assistant launch (and again cancel it), or to try to put my own custom function, by trying to understand the bluetooth frame / finding some code of the app ?


These are some messy thoughts, because I don't know if something in this fashion could be done. Any idea or advice is greatly appreciated.

I'd check and see if the touchpad is generating media button presses.  In your activity, override onKeyDown and check if a an event occurs when they press it.  If so, map those buttons to whatever you want.
